# Can't receive plain text from my Java Server app in Google Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome

I have a little server app written in Java, which sends plain text to the browser like this:

**Server.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Server {

private int portNumber;

public Server(int portNumber) {
    this.portNumber = portNumber;
}

public void start() {
    //Thread pool
    final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                while(true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = ss.accept();
                    threadPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread clientThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    clientThread.start();
}
}
```

**ClientTask.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientTask implements Runnable{

private final Socket clientSocket;

public ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Got a client...");

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());){
        os.writeBytes("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
        os.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain");
        os.writeBytes("\r\n");
        os.writeBytes("\r\n");
        os.writeBytes("hello");
        os.writeBytes("\r\n");
        os.flush();
        System.out.println("About to close..");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server(1111);
    server.start();
}
}
```

My server runs on port 1111 and when I type `http://localhost:1111` in Safari it works perfectly well(I see "hello" in the browser ) but not in Chrome.
What can be the case with **Chrome**?

EDIT: Screenshot with the console's network tab
[image]

Comment: what does your request look like in chrome developers console? Can you make some screenshots with the Network tab?

Comment: @sfat I've edited my question

Comment: are you behind a proxy network? On other browsers besides safari does it work? Also, you might want to try in `incognito mode` in chrome, might some sort of cache problem.

Comment: I'm not behing a proxy network. I've also tried in Firerox and in incognito mode, it didn't work..

Comment: please, post your `js` code (if there is any) and full server-side method you are requesting

Comment: I don't have any `js` code, only Java, which I've added to my question

Comment: Thats pretty weird I copied your code and tried it in Chrome, Chrome incognito and Microsoft Edge and it seemed to work on my machine

Comment: That means something it's wrong with my Chrome

Comment: I have the same issue with Chrome, also with `curl` (`* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What output you send in `DataOutputStream` is wrong, basically Chrome would accept a valid HTTP response to receive.

Here is your Client updated (I will let you optimize the code)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class ClientTask implements Runnable {

    private final Socket clientSocket;

    public ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Got a client...");

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
             DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream())) {
            String message = "Hello";
            os.writeBytes("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
            final String currentDateFormatted = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));
            os.writeBytes("Date: " + currentDateFormatted + "\r\n");
            os.writeBytes("Server: Java Server/12234\r\n");
            os.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n");
            os.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + message.length() + "\r\n");
            os.writeBytes("Expires: " + currentDateFormatted + "\r\n");
            os.writeBytes("Last-modified: " + currentDateFormatted + "\r\n");
            os.writeBytes("\r\n");
            os.write(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            System.out.println("About to close..");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Tested on Chrome and using `curl` via terminal:

```
curl -v localhost:1111
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:1111/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 1111 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:1111
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 24 Mar 2018 11:27:15 GMT
< Server: Java Server/12234
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 5
< Expires: Sat, 24 Mar 2018 11:27:15 GMT
< Last-modified: Sat, 24 Mar 2018 11:27:15 GMT
<
* Closing connection 0
Hello%
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably Chrome redirects from http:// to https://

To prevent this behavior go to chrome://net-internals/#hsts, enter localhost under Delete domain security policies and press the Delete button.